# Values of expressions containing eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a 2x2 Hermitian matrix, with eigenvalues λ<sub>1</sub> and λ<sub>2</sub>, with corresponding normalised eigenvectors of e<sub>1</sub> and e<sub>2</sub>,

How do I find the values of:
Im{λ<sub>1</sub>λ<sub>2</sub>} and e<sub>1</sub>†(e<sub>1</sub>+e<sub>2</sub>)?

Comment: So you do not have the eigenvalues and -vectors. You have just the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is hermitian, its eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots \lambda_n$ are real, so $\text{Im }(\lambda_1\lambda_2\ldots\lambda_n)=0$.

Comment: P.S. I don't know what the symbol † means.

Comment: † means transpose and taking the conjugate.

Comment: I denote it by $*$. Then, $e_1^*(e_1+e_2)=e_1^*e_1+e_1^*e_2=\langle e_1,e_1\rangle+\langle e_1,e_2\rangle=\left\|{e_1}\right\|^2+0=1$, because $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis.